# How shorthand for assign more property object in js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
Obj.a = xxx
Obj.b = yyy
Obj.c = zzz
```

I want to just typing to

```
With(obj){
a = xxx
b = yyy
c = zzz
}
```

With syntex is deprecate 
in es6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can use spread operator.

```
const obj = {...{}, a: "xxx", b: "yyy", c: "zzz"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(obj, {
  a: xxx,
  b: yyy,
  c: zzz,
})
```